# tcp variability on same host

Tags: linux, tcp

I have a tcp client and server which run on the same host. The client sends the message, server acks it and client sends the next message. At any moment, there is only one outstanding un-acked message. Message size is 1KB. The home computer runs CentOs 6.3 and office server runs RHEL 6.3

When i run the above client server on my home computer, i get a very consistent throughput of roughly 41k messages per second. The office server has only 1% CPU load. But if i run the same client/server on my office server, i get throughput ranging from 18k-50K....highly fluctuating throughput. Can anyone offer suggestions as to

1. What could be likely causes of fluctuation for tcp on the same host?
2. Any ideas on how to debug tcp performance ?

UPDATE:-
I am not using loopback address, rather IP assigned to the eth1. Though it should not matter that the IP of eth1 is not in /etc/hosts as the first request would cause lookup to be cached.

UPDATE 1:-
Running on loopback address, yields the same fluctuating output. 
Also, when i look at `cat /proc/interrupts`, i see 5 rx queues and one tx queue per NIC. Is it the 5rx queues causing variability?

Comment: 'I get throughput ranging from 18k-50K'. 18k-50k what? K or k isn't a measure of throughput.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possibilities I can think of immediately:

- Packet drop, which causes the congestion window to shrink (improbably in your case on localhost)
- Application bottleneck, which would cause the receiver window to shrink (less improbable than the first)
- Traffic shaping that for some reason applies to localhost. Try `tc qdisc` and see if there's something on lo. Also have a look at iptables.
- CPU scheduling throttling your client or server. Do you have a CPU share imposed via cgroups that could be preempting your processes from time to time?
- An intermittent overhead, such as logging that starts somewhere during your test and delays packets from arriving. Or an IDS suddenly decides to start watching your activity.
- Measurement inaccuracies, such as running the test for too short a period
- Live lock degradations because of excessive queue thrashing. This paper provides good insight on such cases: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~brecht/papers/getpaper.php?file=usenix-2004.pdf
- A bug in your client or server. E.g. you should be checking that send() returns 1024 and take appropriate action if not, rather than assuming that everything went through if there was no error.

The way I would debug this is:

- Start by using a standard measurement tool, such as iperf (yum install iperf). Then `iperf -s` on one terminal, `iperf -c localhost` on another. Do you get stable results, if so then the issue is a bug in your client and server.
- If it's TCP, then iperf provides some diagnostics like printing window sizes periodically. You can also check the `lo` interface for packet drops, along with other statistics in /proc/sys/ipv4.